# Multiplication of matrix containing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Defining $$ A  =  \begin{bmatrix}a_{11}& a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix} 
; B = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$  A_U = \begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}; B_L\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$$
How do I go about proving that: $$ A_UB_L =  \begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$$ for all n x n matrices A and B?

Can I perform the usual matrix multiplication (elements in a matrix) on such a matrix $A_U and B_L$ (matrix of matrices)? Or do I have to use summation notation / induction to prove this?

Edit:

I meant
$$\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix} X \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}AI&0\\0&IB\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$$

Is the above a sufficient proof?

Thank you!

Comment: Below is an abstract algebraic answer, but it's both not hard and enlightening to show the result directly. In particular, it's worth exploring how the direct product of matrices and matrix multiplication relate. E.g., can you say $(A \oplus B)^2 = A^2 \oplus B^2$? Why or why not? If this is true, can this be generalized? If it's false, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Actually, if $B$ is a ring, that is to say a set with two operations $+$ and $\times$ (with usual properties), you can defined the set of matrices $\mathcal M_{m,n}(B)$ with elements that belongs to $B$ and the usual operations $+$ and $\times$ for such matrices (with exactly the same definition as for $\mathcal M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ for instance).

Here, you just need to take $B = \mathcal M_2(\mathbb R)$ and do your computation.